# Sort a table but keep groups of rows together

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How do I sort a table by it's minimum value per group but at the same time keep a group of rows together. Below a simple example of what i am trying to accomplish. The table is sorted by the lowest group value, but the group remains together. I am pretty sure this question has been asked already but i could not find an answer.

```
+---------+-------+
|  Group  | value |
+---------+-------+
|    1    |  3.99 |
|    1    | 10.99 |
|    3    | 12.69 |
|    1    | 20.95 |
|    2    | 19.95 |
|    3    | 10.09 |
+---------+-------+
```

Desired output

```
+---------+-------+
|  Group  | value |
+---------+-------+
|    1    |  3.99 |
|    1    | 10.99 |
|    1    | 20.95 |
|    3    | 10.69 |
|    3    | 12.09 |
|    2    | 19.95 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It will order the group then the value. This is not what i want, and will not generated the desired output. I noticed the down vote, please leave a comment if this question is wrong, unclear or something else so that I can edit and improve it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can sort with window functions:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by min(value) over(partition by grp), value
```

In earlier versions, one option is to join an aggregate subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
    select grp, min(value) min_value from mytable group by grp
) m on m.grp = t.grp
order by m.min_value, t.value
```

Comment: Running mysql 5.7.2 so: order by min(value) over(partition by grp) is not an option. But interesting option for the future.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VALUE,ID) FROM TEMP

Comment: Please include some explanation about how this query solves the problem. Specifically, a brief description of the OVER clause and what it does - this is something that is VERY new to MySQL - most MySQL devs have probably never heard of it.